# Crontab can not run ruby script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I can run the following tasks manually

But it doesn't work with crontab

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh

0,30 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /data-crowler/google && ruby google.rb'

0,30 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /data-crowler/yahoo && ruby yahoo.rb'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /data-crowler/config/schedule.rb
```

## UPDATE

Cron job couldn't run in docker/ubuntu

## This is my cron file

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
* * * * * echo $PATH >> /root//reboot_record.txt >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
* * * * * cd /home/poc/lazy-bird/j && ruby j.rb >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
* * * * * echo $PATH >> /root//reboot_record.txt >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
* * * * * cd /home/poc/lazy-bird/p && ruby p.rb >> /tmp/cron_debug_log.log 2>&1
```

First I add the file into `/etc/crontab`

```
ADD cron_lazy_bird /etc/crontab
```

And I run it with `cron  && tail -f /var/log/cron.log`

However it doesn't run and no log in `/tmp/cron_debug_log.log`

Comment: Try adding an absolute path to the `ruby` executable.

Comment: What errors do you see? Any emailed errors (run mailx if your system is not configured to send locally-generated emails anywhere)? Anything in the system's cron log?